# Creating a global custom session validator in restlet

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

I want to create a global custom session validator for my restlet. One sessionkey will be passed through the header and using that the session is validated . IS there any way to do that globally instead of putting the same code in every resource class ?

Answer (score 0):

Restlet and REST in general don't need server-side sessions. What was the use case?